# Prefixes in XSD in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, intellisense

I am new to XSD, I am wondering how do we know that we have to use prefixes or namespaces in the XSD.

Above all when I use a namespace and provide a prefix for that, there is no intellisense provided related to the objects in the prefix. How can we manage to know the objects in particular prefix/namespace?

i.e. In the images listed in

[image],

When I use a different prefix other than xsd for the default namespace schema it is not listing anything in the intellisense.

Whereas in

[image]

When I use xsd as prefix it is showing the elements in the intellisense.

Is there any specific reason for this and how can we see the elements with other name spaces that are declared with different prefixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that although you have renamed the namespace prefix to ccf, your root node still has the xsd: namespace prefix which is referencing the urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2 namespace (for which it has no definition).

If you were to change it to the below then intellisense would work for ccf:

```
<ccf:schema ... >
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution worked. But there is one more issue where have given the name space as below, when i use <xsd:  i am not able to find out what elements are present in that namespace.

xmlns:xsd="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"